# How to build Android application that uses an API which often gets updated

Tags: android, client-server

I had an idea for my first Android application and it involves Android application talking to a remote server using some API. Now remember, the API here will be used by other web/Android applications as well.

Now the problem is that, the API will be updated often, but the apps installed in my clients mobile, might not be updated frequently. Sometimes, I might also have to introduce a backward incompatible change, which is not supported by older versions of my Android app. What's the best way to do it.

Should I be forcing my clients to update their app?

Comment: You can version your APIs like /api/v1/... and /api/v2/..., you will have to maintain different versions if you want your old apps to still work

Comment: Whether to force users to upgrade is a business decision.  You'll lose X users if you do.  It will cost Y to maintain backwards compatibility.  A user is worth Z.  If X*Z>Y, then maintain backwards compatibility.  If not, don't.  Now figure out those variable.  I'd say in general stay backwards compatible for a few versions, but at some point it isn't worth it.  You can keep track of what versions users are using and kill it when its no longer worth it.